# What comes next in this binary sequence?

Tags: number-sequence

J-001
10111111
11100000

J-002
01001111
11110011

J-003
01110011
11111100

J-004
10000011
11101111

J-005
01010101
11100110

J-006
10010101
11111001

J-007
01101001
11101001

J-008
10101001
11110110

J-009
01011110
11101101

J-010
???????
???????

Also what would these series be?

J-100
???????
???????

J-999
???????
???????

Comment: @moonbutt74 This is actually a representation of a barcode cross-posted from [link](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/25660/interpreting-a-proprietary-stacked-barcode)

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just random?

Comment: It looks like the middle six bits are a counter that increments every other code (I'm treating black as `1` and white as `0`).

Comment: @moonbutt74 Try [Discussion on "What comes next in this binary sequence?"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28847/discussion-on-what-comes-next-in-this-binary-sequence)

Comment: @moonbutt74 I suspect the order you posted below is correct due to the sensors on the reader being labeled SNS1, SNS2 etc from R-L, Top row then Bottom (when inverted against the barcode). I don't currently have access to a reader that will spit out any useful information, only one that will beep if a valid barcode is detected. I do have access to a sample set of barcodes up to J-140 however I want to generate more up to J-999 if possible.

Comment: I just found out about the [reverse-engineering stack exchange](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/): the folks there may be better able to help you.

Answer (score 3):

I'm cheating a little and basing my answer off of [the 120 barcodes](http://s28.postimg.org/5ajf8aobx/barcodes.jpg) the OP [provided in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23925271#23925271).

I'm reading the squares as bits from right-to-left, bottom-to-top, with black as `0` and white as `1`.  Here is the bit numbering I use:

```
16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9
 8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
```

Note that this disagrees with the silkscreened labels on the barcode reader PCB.  I don't think that the hardware labels necessarily correspond to the software's processing order though.

---

The first thing I noticed was that bits `6`-`11` of the barcodes are just `((J - 1) >> 1) & 0x3F` (where `J` is the number printed on each barcode).

However, `J-045`, `J-093`, and `J-101` do not follow this pattern:

- `J-045`: should be `0x16` (22), actually `0x3E` (62)
- `J-093`: should be `0x2E` (46), actually `0x3F` (63)
- `J-101`: should be `0x32` (50), actually `0x3F` (63)

---

There are two other patterns that I am fairly sure about though:

1. Bits `15` and `16` are always opposite of each other.
2. Excluding bit `16`, the number of `1`s is always even.

Therefore I believe that bits `15` and `16` are some form of parity check.

The remaining bits, `1`-`14`, seem to have an additional parity check.  For all the barcodes we have, I found the following relations:

```
xor(    b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7             ) = b11
xor(b1,     b3, b4, b5,         b8, b9     ) = b12
xor(b1, b2,     b4, b5, b6,     b8,     b10) = b13
xor(b1, b2, b3,     b5,     b7,     b9, b10) = b14
```

My best guess is that the first fourteen bits contain a ten-bit value and some sort of four-bit checksum.  However, an exhaustive search of all 4- and 5-bit CRC generator polynomials has not yielded any results.

Comment: I have added a photo of the barcode reader circuit to the my dsp question. The labeling of sensors seems to imply that the barcode is read from right-to-left, top-to-bottom.

Comment: @user1224615 The problem with using the board labeling as the order is that it implies the two parity check bits are in the middle of the full 16-bit word, which my brain doesn't like.  However I'll try that order to see if I can pull a CRC out of the barcode.

Answer (score 2):

[image: ELFlh.jpg]

```
From the barcode image as per OP's
suggestion of read order [R->L&T->B]
and by 2012rcampion's suggestion of
BLACK=1 WHITE=0

j-001 11111101 00000111

j-002 11110010 11001111

j-003 11001110 00111111

j-004 11000001 11110111

j-005 10101010 01100111

j-006 10101001 10011111

j-007 10010110 10010111

j-008 10010101 01101111

j-009 01111010 10110111

j-010 01100001 00101111

j-011 01011101 11011111

j-012 01000110 01000111

j-013 00110001 01010111

j-014 00100110 11111111

j-015 00011010 00001111

j-016 00001101 10100111

j-017 11111001 01111110

j-018 11101110 11010110

j-019 11010010 00100110

j-020 11000101 10001110
```

Comment: This is about as far as I got. One thing to note is that the sequence is not necessarily read from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to convert the Second Byte of Binary to ASCII 
from J-001 to J-009 and I got:

> à ó ü ï æ ù é ö í 
>
>    the English vowels in Latin so maybe it's a coincidence, but I think The second bit of J-010 is à so it would be 11100000, But I don't know about the first Bytes and how they are connected, Maybe they tell which vowel letter is the second byte...